# Google Analytics - How to fill Tracker fields related to Adwords Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

GA Tracker fields like 'Campaign Name', 'Campaign Keyword' etc are used to send info to GA but how do they get set? I presume by code that I have to write and is executed on the web page.

In Adwords I would need to set up Tracking Templates in conjuction with Custom Parameters and then extract that info from the query string of the just landed upon page, set the appropriate Tracker fields, and Send to GA.

AM I in the ball park here or is there a more 'magical way' of short cutting this because Adwords and GA are hopefully really great friends?

Comment: Link your Adwords- and Analytics-Accounts in the property  settings of the GA account. This  will enable Autotagging in Adwords. Your Ads will be automatically tagged with the "google click id" (gclid) query Parameter. Google Analytics will use this parameter as a key to pull the campaign data from the linked Adwords account. Since this is a configuration issue and not about programming it is not actually on topic, though.

Comment: Thank you Eike for posting.